# python .loc confusion. help using str.endswith

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to retrieve a value with the following last 3 letters using LOC to run through my data dictionary

```
Bnew = df.loc[df.Column == (str.endswith('TCB')
```

Please help me find the format to do this.

Thank you!!!

Comment: Do you mean `df.loc[df.Column.str.endswith('TCB')]`?

Comment: pelase use tags, so others know the scope of your quesiton

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
Bnew = df[df["Column"].str.endswith('TCB')]
```

Added example of it working on a simple dataframe -

[image: working in python]

Comment: unfortunately that did not help! thanks for giving it ago. I am getting a traceback error

Comment: I tried something else and I feel like I'm getting closer to a solution what do you suppose I use as an argument apart from the string im looking for ?Bnew=df.loc[df.Column(str.endswith('TCB'))]                                                                                         THE ERROR IM GETTING= TypeError: endswith() takes at least 1 argument (0 given)

Comment: The syntax you are using is wrong.  it should be `Bnew=df.loc[df.Column.str.endswith('TCB')]`. Make sure you have a column named `Column` in the dataframe.
Also, please share the error you are getting using the method I posted in the answer.  I have added a screenshot of it working on a simple dataframe.